# How to define flask SERVER_NAME correctly for deployment

Tags: python, azure, flask, server, subdomain

My flask website used to work correctly until I had to define a subdomain with flask.

For the subdomain to work, the (SERVER_NAME) should be configured and point to the host address (mywebsite1.com) instead of IP.

This worked with me correctly on the local machine, **however after deployment to an azure host following error keeps printing**, and the website not working:

```
self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address
```

I tried to define the SERVER_NAME in different ports and it **did not work after deployment**:

```
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'mywebsite1.com:80'
```

and

```
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'mywebsite1.com:5000'
```

The only way my website working is when defining the localhost this way, but subdomains not detected and always point to the homepage:

```
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = '0.0.0.0:5000'
```

Please help to define SERVER_NAME that works on Azure host and docker.